# Como fazer o programa exibir uma mensagem uma única vez no último dia do mês?

Tags: c#, modelagem

Estou trabalhando no desenvolvimento de um programa financeiro em  Windows Forms e apareceu um requisito que ainda não estou sabendo como fazer. O requisito é o seguinte:

> No último dia do mês ao abrir o programa pela primeira vez, o mesmo deve perguntar se deseja gerar os boletos de todas as parcelas a serem pagas no mês seguinte e caso positivo, gerar esses boletos todos de uma vez.

O programa já tem um mecanismo de geração de boleto usando a biblioteca BoletoNet. Na verdade, há uma tela que mostra as parcelas e permite gerar o boleto para as parcelas selecionadas. O mecanismo é o mesmo, a única diferença é que o programa precisaria pegar todas as parcelas a serem pagas no mês seguinte e executar o código de geração de boleto em cima delas.

Até aí tudo bem. O problema que existe é o seguinte: como fazer o programa no último dia do mês mostrar essa mensagem uma única vez?

Fazer exibir uma mensagem dessa no último dia do mês é fácil. Basta colocar um `if` que verifica se hoje é o último dia do mês e caso positivo abre a janela com a pergunta e as opções sim e não.

O problema é fazer essa mensagem aparecer uma *única* vez. E na verdade acho que até seria necessário ter uma opção: "mostrar depois" para que a mensagem volte a ser mostrada mais uma vez depois.

Enfim, o problema é que para isso seria necessário uma noção de estado disso. Mas eu acho que fazer uma tabela no banco de dados só pra armazenar se naquele mês a janela foi mostrada ou não é um absurdo. Nem faz sentido, porque esse tipo de janela poderia ser usada para mais coisas e aí teria uma tabela para cada?

O que eu quero saber é: como eu posso fazer com que essa janela seja mostrada uma só vez?

**Edição:** Em atenção aos comentários, vou adicionar essa edição para explicar um pouco melhor. O requisito foi apresentado assim mesmo. E para falar a verdade é difícil conseguir mais explicações. Nesse projeto várias vezes tentei conseguir mais explicações sobre os requisitos mas em geral não conseguimos muito esclarecimento não.

De volta ao requisito em si: o usuário pediu para abrir uma vez só no dia. Para não abrir outra vez teríamos que ter gravado em algum lugar que naquele mes já foi aberto. Daí em memoria não é suficiente.

Por outro lado, há outras variáveis e considerações que me fizeram postar a pergunta para avaliar a melhor maneira de conseguir isso. Primeiro que esse tipo de interação deve ocorrer para outras coisas. Por exemplo, o usuário quer que no primeiro dia do mês o programa abra uma vez só uma janela perguntando se quer enviar os boletos gerados no último dia do mês anterior. Daí é o mesmo tipo de situação.

Além disso há variáveis a se considerar: (1) e se o usuário quiser ser lembrado mais tarde? (2) seria necessário também uma verificação da existência de parcelas para gerar boleto? (3) e se o usuário cria uma nova cobrança no mesmo dia?

São só algumas perguntas que fazem considerar a necessidade de ter uma noção de *estado* disso. Por outro lado, pensei em utilizar uma tabela para todos esses tipos de ações, de forma abstrata pensando só na regra de negocio. Algo do seguinte tipo: cria-se uma tabela `acoes_periodicas` com colunas `id` , `tipo_acao`, `data`, `situacao`. O `tipo_acao` descriminaria o que é feito periodicamente, e.g., `geracao_boleto_mes`, `envio_boletos_mes`. A data conteria informação do mês e a situação conteria a informação se foi feito ou se foi adiado.

Essa foi só uma primeira ideia, mas achei um pouco estranha. A maior estranheza é: a coluna `tipo_acao` teria que ter somente alguns valores predefinidos que seriam *hardcoded*. Ou seja, quando fosse para abrir a janela do boleto faria uma consulta no banco de dados explicitamente por `geracao_boleto_mes`. Acho que funciona, mas acho estranho. Como a situação é mais geral e pode ser usada em outras situações nas quais um programa precisa pedir a um usuário sempre em um dia do mês para fazer algo, achei válida a pergunta até para outras pessoas e postei.

Comment: Não entendi isso: `esse tipo de janela poderia ser usada para mais coisas e aí teria uma tabela para cada?`

Comment: Removi a tag UX porque a sua pergunta não entra nesse mérito. Se entrasse, aliás, seria ampla demais. Se tiver também essa dúvida, sugiro que abra outra pergunta focada.

Comment: Sobre o "problema", não basta armazenar alguma indicação *em memória*? Afinal, a janela só vai ser exibida no último dia do mês (nunca antes, e tampouco depois). Só durante aquele expediente faz sentido não exibir mais de uma vez. Se o usuário fechar o sistema e abrir de novo, você mostra mais uma vez (o que, de fato, é até consistente). Obviamente você também já deve estar verificando se os boletos *já foram gerados*, não?

Comment: @LuizVieira na verdade a pergunta não está muito claro nos detalhes do requisito, de como o sistema opera, mas ele vai melhorar. Essa é uma solução possível e parece adequada, mas ele fala em lembrar do estado sem dizer porque e quando precisa fazer isso, pode precisar outra solução, e aí pode ser que uma tabela não seria nada absurdo.

Comment: @bigown Sim, concordo. Por isso eu comentei com uma pergunta, ao invés de responder. :)

Comment: Pq não cria uma flag no seu App.config para saber se a mensagem já foi exibida?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 1):

Existem basicamente dois cenários:

- o sistema não funciona em rede

  Não concordo com o Luiz Vieira em comentário, não acho que uma simples indicação na memória funcionaria da melhor forma, a não ser que seja garantido que alguém vai entrar neste dia e ficaria esquisito alguém emitir os boletos e depois ele te perguntar pra emitir de novo. Isso até poderia ser evitado se verificar se tem algum boleto para emitir dentro do critério normal do requisito, se não tem nada não pede para emitir. Não gosto desta solução porque terá que fazer uma consulta potencialmente cara para tomar a decisão, mas se te atende, pode usar que funciona, crédito para o Luiz.

  Se quiser facilitar pode por um indicador no banco de dados que não precisa mais emitir os boletos, uma consulta simples. Isso pode ser em uma tabela  própria específica ou em uma geral de configurações e *flags* já existente.

  Ainda que eu não recomende, também pode ser no registro do Windows, no arquivo de configuração da aplicação ou outros meios. Uma forma mais ou menos aceitável seria criar um arquivo para registrar a condição. Na verdade o arquivo nem precisa de formato, pode ter 0 bytes, a simples existência dele é um indicador. Seria bom verificar a data dele, em algum momento apagar, ou deixar e sempre usar a data para determinar se aquele fez já foi emitido. Acho essas soluções frágeis e não parecem muito corretas.

  O usuário pode mexer nisso e burlar o sistema, até sem querer. No banco de dados é um pouco mais seguro e ele só fará por querer, ou perderá tudo e o problema é bem pior.
- o sistema funciona em rede, provável, né?

  Imagino que se uma pessoa emitiu, ninguém mais pode emitir. Se controlar no cliente fica difícil funcionar. Funcionaria apenas se for garantido que ninguém em outra máquina irá tentar, aí o sistema controlaria por máquina se deve mostrar a tela ou não. Acho bem frágil.

  Se a informação ficará disponível *system wide* tem que persistir em algum lugar. Na memória é ruim, a não ser que possa garantir que o servidor sempre estará ligado. Um pouco frágil. Se é pra guardar em algum lugar não consigo imaginar porque seja um absurdo colocar no banco de dados, mesmo se tiver que criar uma tabela só pra isso.

  Pode evitar criar qualquer coisa no banco de dados se criar uma consulta que verifica se tem boletos a serem emitidos no critério estabelecido e só retornar para o cliente se tem ou não. É uma troca de um espaço irrisório no banco de dados por um processamento que pode não ser tão barato. Prefiro ter um indicador.

O problema nada tem a ver com a interface, uma codificação nela é necessária para cumprir uma regra de negócio. Se é regra de negócio, o banco de dados me parece um lugar mais do que adequado. Você não vai controlar se a tela será exibida ou não, controlará se precisa emitir os boletos no último dia ou não, porque já foram emitidos. A tela é uma consequência da regra de negócio.

Mas imagine, se ninguém entrar nesse dia, o que acontece? Emite no dia seguinte? Acho que sim, né? O usuário não pode querer emitir um dia anates porque ele sabe que amanhã ele não acessará o sistema. Precisa de um controle específico, precisa ser determinado pelo banco de dados de uma forma ou de outra. Tentar tratar um problema de regra de negócio na UI me parece um erro.

Precisa da intervenção de um humano pra fazer isso? O sistema não pode emitir sozinho? Talvez precise, se for o caso precisa pensar nas exceções, se for emitir antes ou depois. Me parece um requisito frágil que o usuário entrará no sistema no dia certo e vai emitir com certeza.

Nem entro no mérito que o requisito também possa estar errado, a não ser que seja garantido que todas condições de emissão de boleto sejam "x dias fora mês, onde x não seja poucos dias", já que emitir dia 31 um boleto que vencerá dia 1 não parece estar certo.

Com a regra de negócio bem definida e persistida corretamente a UX é só um detalhe.

Em atenção à edição:

> O requisito foi apresentado assim mesmo

O requisito é aquele que você colhe e não o que te apresentam. Se o requisito não está claro para o usuário é sua função fazer o requisito chegar em um ponto adequado. Se isso não for possível o melhor a fazer é não fazer o projeto, tem bom argumento em mãos. Se o melhor não for possível então qualquer solução serve.

O usuário deve definir o que ele precisa e não como o sistema funciona.

A não ser que esteja mal descrito aqui o usuário não sabe como trabalha, e aí a melhor coisa a tentar fazer é agir como um analista de processo e tentar arrumar a empresa antes de arrumar o sistema. Tem buracos demais para conseguir fazer alguma coisa que funcione. Parte de premissas erradas, conforme já falei acima.

A edição coloca alguns pontos, eu coloquei outros.

Não sei se é necessário, mas parece que está querendo criar um sistema de Workflow.

Tem que tomar cuidado com essa de "já fez ou não". Precisa ter certeza que está feito mesmo. E esse negócio de tal dia faz, é só uma base inicial, já coloquei acima que pode haver problemas nesse critério e outros critérios precisam ser criados para lidar com isso.

O normal é achar estranho qualquer coisa nunca fez.

Você não conseguirá a solução para um problema que está mal definido.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. Lendo ela cheguei a conclusão que o melhor é persistir no banco de dados mesmo, pois não se trata de questão de interface mas de regra de negocio (o usuário precisar ser lembrado disso a cada tantos dias). Eu até pensei em uma abordagem mas não sei se é razoável. Criaria uma tabela para todas essas "ações periódicas" e marcaria o nome da ação, a data e a situação (se foi feita ou adiada). Aí nesse caso no dia seria criada uma entrada com o nome daquela ação e a situação. Seria na verdade quase a mesma coisa que criar o arquivo. O que acha dessa abordagem?

Comment: @Leonardo parece interessante, mas não posso afirmar sem conhecer o todo, pode ser que tenha uma solução melhor ainda. Só lembre que registrar isso pura e simplesmente pode não funcionar bem, você muito preocupado com o evento quando na verdade a consistência geral do processo é que é importante.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi sua pergunta, você pode salvar nas configurações do usuário se ele já foi avisado ou não:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```
if(UltimoDiaDoMes())
{
    if(!Properties.Settings.Default.AvisouUsuario)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(...);
        Properties.Settings.Default.AvisouUsuario = true;
    }
}
else
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.AvisouUsuario = false;
}
```